# index was outside the bounds of the array meaning WPF C#

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, loops, indexing

I try this code to  display names from database in loop but this shows an error index was outside the bounds of the array meaning on this line
                name[j++] = Convert.ToString(reader["CategoryName"]);

code

```
 con.Open();
        int count =0;
        int j =0;
        //cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Category");
        string[] name = new string[count];
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select CategoryName from Category",con);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            name[j++] = Convert.ToString(reader["CategoryName"]);
        }
        int loc = 37;
        CheckBox[] obj = new CheckBox[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            obj[i] = new CheckBox();
            obj[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(loc, 50);
            obj[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            obj[i].Text = name[i];
            this.Controls.Add(obj[i]);
            loc += 80;

        }
        con.Close();
```

any help?

Comment: You are initializing your `name` array with a size of `0`

Comment: You declare `int count = 0;` and then `string[] name = new string[count];` So name is zero characters long. You then access it and try to write to that zero length array. What would you expect to happen? I know! You'll get an error that says **Index was outside the bounds of the array**. Do I win a prize?

Comment: You initialize `name` as an array with 0 size. Then you try to access an index of your array **which has 0 size** and wonder why you got an index out of bounds exception? Maybe do some googling to make an effort to better understand what the exception is, why it happens, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you set `count = 0` then you create an array with that

```
string[] name = new string[count];
```

Which means your array will be of 0 lenght and you won't be able too assign anything to it.
I suggest you change it to a `List` which will be much easier

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    name.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["CategoryName"]));
}
```

Comment: ok and how to display that name in label?

Comment: @Super You can access the `List` the same way as the array by doing `name[i]`. You can get the amount of items in your list by doing `count = name.Count;`

Answer (score 1):

At the beggining you set

```
int count =0;
```

and then you initialize the array like this:

```
new string[count];
```

you are effectively creating an array with zero places in it.
and then you loop with:

```
name[j++]
```

you access an index in the array that isn't there